# How do I generate a new <View> with the exercise properties when an exercise is selected from the modal in my react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an exercise app that generates a new view. Within that view, users will be able to input weight and sets. In my code I have a modal that generates a list of exercises from a different file. I would then like to select an exercise which should populate a new view in the return with properties of the selected exercise.

Here is the code I have so far

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, Modal, Picker, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList  } from 'react-native';
import myExerciseList from './ExerciseList';
//import Exercise from './ExerciseSets';

const exercises = myExerciseList

const ExerciseList = () => {
  const [views, setViews] = useState([]);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const handlePress = () => {
    const newView = <View style={styles.ExerciseBox} key={views.length} >
                      <Text>Exercise</Text>
                    </View>;
    setViews([...views, newView]);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Render the views */}
      {views}

      {/* Add a new view */}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setVisible(true)}>
          <Text>Select an Exercise</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal visible={visible}>
          <ScrollView>
            {exercises.map((item) => (
              <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} onPress={() => handlePress(item)}>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setVisible(false)}>
              <Text>Cancel</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </ScrollView>
        </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ExerciseBox: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5
  },

})


export default ExerciseList;
```

I have tried creating another hook which then transfers the properties of the selected exercise to the **handlePress** function but I get the error
*NewExercise.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined
at handlePress*

Am I missing something or is my approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The handlePress function needs to have *item* passed as an argument like so

```
 const handlePress = (item) => {
    setSelectedValue(item)
    const newView = <View style={styles.ExerciseBox} key={views.length} >
                      <Text>Exercise</Text>
                      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                    </View>;
    setViews([...views, newView]);
    setVisible(false);
  };
```